App Hosting - Rollout Failed On my nextJS 14.0.3 project
i am in the process of building a nextJS web application, i decided to go with Firebase AppHosting to host my web app with continues rollout using github, within the first 2 commit my app was working and it was rolling our well, however after working on my project for sometimes and pushing new code my firebase apphosting failed to rollout a new version.
i added the apphosting.yaml to my project using the firebase documentation i even increased the spec of the memory and cpu with no luck.
i checked the Google console to see the error but i was not lucky, i did not get any useful information of why this is happening.
i will be thankful if anyone can provide a fix.
runConfig:
  minInstances: 2
  maxInstances: 100
  concurrency: 100
  cpu: 4
  memoryMiB: 8192

Google console error log
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service-1000712175710@gcp-sa-firebaseapphosting.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudbuild.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.CloudBuild.CreateBuild",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/000000e8ff18005e",
        "permission": "cloudbuild.builds.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {},
        "permissionType": "ADMIN_WRITE"
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/iqra-4d3ab/builds",
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "europe-west4"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "-l1lfsxd1ro4",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "iqra-4d3ab",
      "build_trigger_id": "",
      "build_id": "bd90a7af-0a48-43bb-b42b-b023ef2acaee"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-11-19T15:42:40.358277Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/iqra-4d3ab/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/build/iqra-4d3ab/YmQ5MGE3YWYtMGE0OC00M2JiLWI0MmItYjAyM2VmMmFjYWVl",
    "producer": "cloudbuild.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-11-19T15:42:41.266366664Z"
}





Keen to see if anyone has a solution to this as I’m also running into this exact problem.
The lack of logs is swaying me away from App hosting already!
